# create ant to fetch record using php script

Tags: php, ant

I am very new to the ant scripting, I want to create ant script that will execute and grab data from php script and insert data into database.

I have going through previous two question [Running PHP script in background using Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041246/running-php-script-in-background-using-ant) and [build PHP with ant scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154699/build-php-with-ant-scripts) but it is not working for me.

i have tried below code:

```
  <project name="fetch_record_test" basedir="." default="*install"> 
    <target name="*install" depends="test-src">
        <exec executable="${php}" failonerror="true" dir="${source}">
            <arg line="${projectdir}/Connectors/record_mapping.php"/>
            <arg line="-output" />
        </exec>
   </target>
</project>
```

can any one show me ant script to do so.
Thanks

Comment: In what way is it *not working*?

Comment: @martinclayton yes, it is not working for me.

Comment: It's a bit hard for us to assess what's not working.  Don't you think you should say what error messages you're getting?  Or indicate that the process throws no errors if that is the case.  Having said that, try running ant in verbose mode (`ant -v`) and read the messages - perhaps that will give you a clue as to what the problem is.

Comment: @Pragnesh Chauhan epic answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with `${php}` so try to change `executable=${php}` to `executable="php"`

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227463/how-can-i-execute-a-perl-script-using-the-ant-exec-task) for more information.

For storing data in database you can connect your php file with database or use [ant sql](http://ant.apache.org/manual//Tasks/sql.html)